# Defining some simple classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class MSDie(object):
    def __init__(self,sides):
        self.sides = sides
        self.current_side = 1


    def getValue(self):
        return self.current_side

    def roll(self):
        self.current_side = random.randint(1,self.sides)

    def set(self,value):
```

as I am trying to work on my classes, I need the class MSDie to have:

- On the creation of a the instance you should supply the number of sides of the die.
- It should have a getValue() method that returns the current value of the die (the side that is facing up).
- It should contain a roll() method that returns a random value from 1 to the number of sides for the die.
- It should contain a set(value) method that lets a program set the current value of the die (the side that is facing up)
- All instances should have a default current value of 1.**

such as how an example usage of the class would be:

```
sixDie = MSDie(6)
print sixDie.getValue()
sixDie.roll()
print sixDie.getValue()
sixDie.set(4)
print sixDie.getValue()
```

which would yield the output:

1
2 ← randomly generated
4

can anyone help out?

Comment: `radint` = `randint`? Also `set` doesn't look to be implemented. I'm not really sure what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on everything you're asking the class to accomplish you almost have everything setup correctly. I just finished your `set()` method and imported `random` to generate a random int.

Below is everything put together. You can copy it into a Python file and it will run.

```
import random

class MSDie(object):
    def __init__(self,sides):
        self.sides = sides
        self.current_side = 1


    def getValue(self):
        return self.current_side

    def roll(self):
        self.current_side = random.randint(1,self.sides)

    def set(self,value):
        self.current_side = value


sixDie = MSDie(6)
print sixDie.getValue()
sixDie.roll()
print sixDie.getValue()
sixDie.set(4)
print sixDie.getValue()
```